# What is the right way to call values from a bean in jsp page?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, jstl, javabeans

I am working on a java MVC project. Currently i've a `login.jsp`, ``` profile.jsp, ``CheckLogin ``` servlet, `User.java` bean class and `UserDAO` dao class (the beans and jsp's and all other things are to be added also).
What i am currently doing here whenever the user gets logged in successfully it is redirected to the profile page which shows all the details of user.
My question here is:

**Is it better to set a `User` type object for particular `userID` in the `session` object that prevails in whole `session` and retrieve all values directly as `${sessionScope.user.property}` everywhere?**

*or*

**Is it better to set just a `userID` in the `session` object that prevails in whole `session` and retrieve the values in all pages using  these lines of code :**
`<jsp:useBean id="userDAO" scope="page" type="com.project.dao.UserDAO" />`
`<c:set var="user" value="<%= userDAO.getUser(%>${sessionScope.userID}<%) %>" />`
`${user.property}`

I hope i am clear to you in my question.
Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

First rule: avoid scriptlets. The fact that you have no other solution than scriptlets shows a design problem. The controller should prepare the model for the view. The view should not call DAOs directly. That's the responsibility of the controller.

Now, storing the user in the session or loading it at each request (from the controller) is a matter of performance and stale data.

If the user only contains data that won't change through the whole session (or that could change, but only from this session, allowing to refresh the data when needed), then store it in the session. That's its goal: store data that have a session scope.

If there might be some external session or process modifying the data of the user, and you want to make sure you always display the freshest data, then reload it at every request.

Comment: If I not use `UserDAO` in this situation then what may be the other way to get a `User` object for particular jsp page? please suggest the design issue..

Comment: I didn't say that you shouldn't use the UserDAO. I said that it should not be called from the view (the JSP). It should be called by the controller (the servlet), and the user should be stored in the session or request before dispatching to the JSP. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#Example